# Make HttpWebRequest write/upload immediately, so I can track progress

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, progress, webrequest

I've been googling this for a while with no luck. It also appears many other people have had this problem but those who have don't seem to explain how they solved it. I've tried to apply all the things suggested by others (AllowWriteStreamBuffering, SendChunked), but still can't get this to work.

If I run the following code, with a _data set of 30MB, the code within the using(reqStream) block executes in a fraction of a second, and then it stalls on the request.GetResponse line where it appears to do the upload.

I'm wanting it to instead upload the chunks as it does the write, so that I can show how much data has been uploaded, to show progress.

What am I doing wrong?

```
static void Upload(string _url, Byte[] _data)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(_url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = _data.Length;
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            request.SendChunked = true;

            using (var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                var bytesWritten = 0;
                while (bytesWritten != _data.Length)
                {
                    var amountToWrite = Math.Min(1000000, _data.Length - bytesWritten);
                    reqStream.Write(_data, bytesWritten, amountToWrite);
                    reqStream.Flush();

                    // report progress

                    bytesWritten += amountToWrite;
                }
            }

            var response = request.GetResponse();
            var resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```